# How to pass a textbox value from an ASP.NET MVC view to a SQL Server parameter

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to this is it is possible to send a textbox value from an ASP.NET MVC view to a SQL Server parameter.

For example:

- ASP.NET MVC view:  Name:mike
- Html code: `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="myinput4"  name="mike" />`
- SQL query:

  ```
  DECLARE @value varchar(10)  
  SET @value = '@name'
  ```

Is it possible?

Comment: I think may be asking how to pass a parameter, not a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You could try below which could help you to achieve the above.

`MVC` View Page:

```
<Script type="text/javascript">

var txtval = $('#myinput4').val();

function SaveTextValue(txtval) {
            window.location.href = '/ControllerName/ActionName?Name=' + txtval;
        }
</script>
```

`Controller` Server Side:

Create Action in Controller with one string parameter.

Example:

```
 public ActionResult SaveTextValue(string Name)
 {
// write logic for store Name(text) value into DB table using inline query or stored procedure.
 }
```